# How to access a new spree model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am new to spree, I have created a new spree model

```
module Spree    
    class VerificationDocument < ActiveRecord::Base

    end
end
```

When I am trying to access the model from console it's showing an error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::VerificationDocument
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Where is your model defined? If it's defined in `app/models/verification_document.rb' it should be auto-loaded by Rails and work.

Comment: @gmacdougall no my model is under model/spree/verification_document.rb

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. It should be at `app/models/spree/verification_document.rb`. It it's not at that exact path, Rails autoloading won't work correctly.

Comment: @gmacdougall yes it not working .. but is the any way ?

Comment: It should work as @gmacdougall said. Please, double check paths and names. Maybe you have a typo. If not, please provide project structure.