# How to access a customised spree model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, console, spree

I am new to spree. I created a new model in spree and was having issue in accessing it. I found this link with similar question but it did'nt reached to any satisfying answer.
[How to access a new spree model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466675/how-to-access-a-new-spree-model)

The model that I ceated

```
module Spree
    class Spree::ClinicDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user, class_name: 'Spree::User', foreign_key: :spree_user_id
    end
end
```

On accessing it through console I was getting the error

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Spree::Clinic_Detail
```

Please answer to my query. It would be a great help to me. Thankyou. Sorry if I am wrong in anyway and correct me please.

Comment: How did you access it through console? Why does it say `Unable to autoload constant Spree::Clinic_Detail` (with an underscore)?

Comment: I used the following command  
user = Spree::Clinic_Detail.find(1)
where I had a hard coded entry in my postres db.
The full error that it gave is:  
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Spree::Clinic_Detail ,expected /var/www/html/projectr/app/models/spree/clinic_detail.rb to define it
from /home/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in `load_missing_constant'

Comment: The Clinic_Detail model name is having a underscore itself. @JagdeepSingh Thankyou for your response. Please help me to solving my issue.

Comment: Try `Spree::ClinicDetail.find(1)`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thankyou. It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion and the error:

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Spree::Clinic_Detail

I get, you are trying to access it through `Spree::Clinic_Detail.find(1)` while the model you defined it `Spree::ClinicDetail` (without an underscore).

So, you need to access it as below:

```
Spree::ClinicDetail.find(1)
```